# psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication

Tags: python, postgresql

I am new to python and postgresql. This is the first time i was trying to connect python to postgresql.But i am getting this error:

```
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vishal/Courses/database/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    user.save_to_db()
  File "/home/vishal/Courses/database/user.py", line 13, in save_to_db
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='1234', database='learning', host='localhost')
  File "/home/vishal/Courses/database/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`
```

Even i tried changing the password and creating new user with different password the result is same.
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Have you configured your `pg_hba.conf` after the installation of PostgreSQL?

Comment: @JimJones No. Should I?

Comment: Look in PostgreSQL server's log file for a full message.  The message returned to the unauthenticated (presumed hostile) user is intentionally vague.